# Does the .clone() method always make a deep copy?

Tags: rust

While reading through a few of the Rust docs, I came across the following;

> ... use `.clone()` to explicitly copy the data.

The choice of "copy" here kind of puzzled me, specifically whether I can always replace "copy" with "deep copy" and for the statement to always hold true.

To my understanding, the `Clone` trait indicates the possibility of either a shallow or deep copy of the data type implementing it, but the explicit use of `.clone()` method will create a deep copy.

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. If not, what are some examples the method does not create a "deep" copy of an object?

Comment: How `clone()` will be implemented will depend on the type. The compiler only requires it to return a `T` given an `&T`. The contract of the trait is somewhat vague, it speaks of "duplicating" and "returning a copy of" a value. Intuitively,  the requirement is that the copy behaves and has the same meaning as the original. This applies to both cloning a `Vec<Vec<,u32>>` and cloning an `Arc<Vec<Vec<u32>>` - although one is deep copy and the other shallow (or no copy at all, depending on what you count as copy), in both cases you get a value that is equivalent to the original.

Comment: The whole question is kinda...off-base? In managed languages the question makes sense but in Rust unless you are explicitly dealing with a pointer type like `Rc` or `Arc` how could it possibly be anything other than deep? Calling `.clone` returns an *owned* type, meaning it owns all the memory allocated to hold the thing. The original owner can't still own the memory holding the original thing (or even part of the thing for aggregates), so it implies a deep copy. Similarly for a shared pointer it makes sense that calling `clone` gives you a copy of the *pointer*, not the thing pointed at.

Comment: ...also Rust does not have objects. I realize that Rust structs kinda sorta look like objects if you squint and they meet many criteria of objects from OO languages (ditto for traits and interfaces), but it's not a perfect fit and I suspect you are being lead astray by the superficial similarity when in this case the difference matters.

Comment: @JaredSmith I agree with your sentiment, but I've got one small nit: `.clone()` only returns an owned type if `T` happens to be an owned type. If `T` is, say, a shared reference, then `.clone()` will return a copy of the reference. It sometimes confuses people that `"Hello".clone()` doesn't really do anything useful.

Comment: @SvenMarnach good point, I guess it never occurred to me to clone references :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

No. It is true that `Clone` can be either shallow (e.g. `Rc`) or deep (e.g. `Box`) copy, but it is always triggered by calling `.clone()`, so `.clone()` can make a shallow copy too (depending on the type).